# Inserting data from MySql to Json array

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm fetching data from Mysql from table person(id, name, email). The table has many rows.
I'm trying to put into a json array in a loop. But in the json array it gets overwritten with the new array.

```
   for row in results:
        persons = {
                     [{
                        'personId' : row[0],
                        'personName' : row[1],
                        'personEmail' : row[2]
                    },]
                 }
    print json.dumps(persons)
```

can anybody give a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, in each iteration of the for loop, you're rebuilding persons as a Python dictionary with one member which is the current row, not adding more rows ("people") to the dictionary. You need to rewrite that, something along the lines of :

```
persons={}
for row in results:
    persons[row[0]] = {                    
                        'personId' : row[0],
                        'personName' : row[1],
                        'personEmail' : row[2]                    
                 }
print json.dumps(persons)
```

Comment: hey, for this solution, i get the result in this format code
`{
  "1": {
    "personId": 1, 
    "personName": "Amritha D",
    "personEmail": "amritha.dilip@outlook.com"
  }, 
  "2": {
    "personId": 2, 
    "personName": "Aishwarya R", 
    "personEmail": "aishwarya1411@gmail.com"
  }
}`
but i want the json array without the indexes "1","2", in this format code
`{
  {
    "personId": 1, 
    "personName": "Amritha D",
    "personEmail": "amritha.dilip@outlook.com"
  }, 
  {
    "personId": 2, 
    "personName": "Aishwarya R", 
    "personEmail": "aishwarya1411@gmail.com"
  }
}`

Comment: So don't use a dictionary, but a list. initialize `persons=[]` and just use `persons.append(....)` in each iterator of the for loop.

Comment: It works well when i'm using `json.dumps(persons)` but I also want to send it as a response in my web application. So, when i use `jsonify(persons)` (using flask) it gives an error. I dont know why?